# Powershell script to stop the windows service not working . No error is thrown either

Tags: windows, powershell

This script has a function that accepts a parameter (service to be  stopped). I ran the script the following way. But the service wouldn't stop. Also for some reason nothing is being written to the console. Where is the Write-Host is writing to? I am using Powershell Version 4.0 on windows 8 OS.

```
  .\MywindowsService.ps1 Dhcp -force 

  function StopWindowsService
  {
         Param([string] $ServiceName)
         $aService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
        if ($aService.Status -ne "Stopped")
        {
               Stop-Service $ServiceName
               Write-Host "Stopping " $ServiceName " service" 
               " ---------------------- " 
              " Service is now stopped"
         }

        if ($aService.Status -eq "stopped"){ 
             Write-Host "$ServiceName service is already stopped"
        }

   }
```

Comment: Remove the `function` declaration, `StopWindowsService` is never called.

Comment: .\MywindowsService.ps1 StopWindowsService Dnscache -force. Still doesn't work. I tried to stop that service from services console. I get an "internal error". May be I need to reboot my computer and try the powershell function again. BTW, do you know why "Write-Host" is not able to write to the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this - **mywindowsservice.ps1:**

```
Param([string] $ServiceName)

$aService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

if ($aService.Status -ne "Stopped") {
    Stop-Service $ServiceName
    Write-Host "Stopping " $ServiceName " service"
    " ---------------------- "
    " Service is now stopped"
}

if ($aService.Status -eq "stopped") {
    Write-Host "$ServiceName service is already stopped"
}
```

**Call:**

```
.\mywindowsservice.ps1 dhcp
```

Declaring `function StopWindowsService` means you need to call `StopWindowsService` inside the ps1 file to actually execute the code. It is not needed here.

Comment: @Jason I've added an explanation